# DI Interfaces and Derived Class usage in Razor View (non-static classes)

Tags: c#, razor, interface, static

I'm building an MVC App, and I have an interface, and a derived class implementing the interface, and DI linking the two together. The functionality in the derived class works perfectly fine in all code calling it in controllers' or model class code, but now, I found an instance of a View I was creating that also would've benefited from using this derived class. But then I found out that this isn't possible because the derived class is non-static, and using it in the View required it to be static. So, I tried to make the interface and derived class static, but then found out interfaces cannot have static designations, and the derived class linked to the interface cannot use static neither, since the interface isn't using static. I even tried to create an razor helper, but even then, since the razor helper I was creating was static (which, from what I think I know, is supposed to be static to work properly), the derived class usage there also is having the same static/non-static problem. I tried finding other questions at stackoverflow that could point me in the right direction, but from what I've seen, I have had no luck, so I ask this question here, hopefully someone can help me out, it would be greatly appreciated. If any more information is required on my end to help you help me, such as some of my code, just ask.

Comment: You can use the inject key word but only with aspnet mvc 6/core. Otherwise you should send the result of your interface from your controller to your view through the model.

Comment: I just thought about your suggestion, and, first off, I'm using mvc 5. And, I'm actually planning on learning how to use  mvc 6/core asap, but not just yet. So, at the current time, I'm stuck with mvc 5. And, the truth is, when it comes to your suggestion in the case of mvc 5, I actually had considered that idea before your suggestion. The thing is how I intend to implement the derived class in the View depends on iterations in a for loop, and was assuming that it might not make sense to provide the class through the model. But, now that I think about it, it might just work, I'll try it

Comment: ...tomorrow, and if it works, I'll let you know, otherwise, if I have further problems, I'll ask you, or anyone else that provides any other suggestions for further help.

Comment: Wow, your answer was so obvious, I should've thought of it. Thanks for trying to help though. But, I would say your answer was also insightful, letting me know about something I'm yet to learn about the new mvc 6/core. You can copy and paste your answer as an answer post and I'll mark it as the answer, or if you don't do that today, I'll just mark my question post as the answer, since the answer is contained in the comments (your comment...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inject key word but only with aspnet mvc 6/core.
See [AspNet core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection).

The syntax for @inject: `@inject <type> <variable_name>`

At the top of your cshtml file, add :

```
@inject StatisticsService StatsService
```

Otherwise you should send the result of your interface from your controller to your view through the model.